# Kotlin smart casts vs null checks vs elvis operator for thread safety

Tags: kotlin

I've seen some code do things like

```
// value is a member of this class, so smart cast
// to non nullable doesn't happen
if (value != null) return value!!
```

Because value is a member of the class, can't a thread change value to null in between the check and the return?  Thus causing a crash?

Here is a more complete example with two different approaches.  Is one better than the other in terms of thread safety?

```
class Example {
  private var cachedVariable: SomeClass? = null

  fun getCachedVariable(): SomeClass {
    // need to use !! because can't smart cast because 
    // mutable property.  But cant this crash if some 
    // other thread sets cachedVariable to null after 
    // this thread does the check?
    if (cachedVariable != null) return cachedVariable!!
    
    cachedVariable = SomeClass()
    return cachedVariable!!
  }
}
```

Or

```
class Example2 {
  private var cachedVariable: SomeClass? = null

  fun getCachedVariable(): SomeClass {
    // Does this avoid the possible crash of Example 1
    return cachedVariable ?: SomeClass().also { 
      cachedVariable = it
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're correct, if it's a var then another thread can change it right in the middle of that line. That's why this code only compiles with !!, as the compiler knows that it can't be sure if the value is null or not. This also relates to how !! usually indicates code smell, you normally expect null-safe code in Kotlin but this construct isn't. This explicitly means that it can crash.

Answer (score 2):

Even your second example is buggy even though it won't crash. Consider this sequence of operations

1. thread 1 enters `getCachedVariable`. sees `cachedVariable` is null
2. thread 2 enters `getCachedVariable`. sees `cachedVariable` is null
3. thread 1 creates `SomeClass()` and assigns it to `cachedVariable`
4. thread 2 creates `SomeClass()` and assigns it to `cachedVariable`

No crash, but now both threads reference different objects and thread 1's object will be garbage collected if thread 1's reference to it is dropped.

It looks like what you really want is `lazy`

```kotlin
class Example {
  val cachedVariable by lazy { SomeClass() }
}
```

that will be computed at most once per instance of `Example` even if multiple threads try to access it, and all threads will safely get the same instance.

Answer (score 2):

> Because value is a member of the class, can't a thread change value to null in between the check and the return? Thus causing a crash?

That is correct, and it's exactly why the compiler won't do a smart cast to non-null here. You can work around the issue by using a local variable:

```
val localValue = value
if (localValue != null) return localValue // no non-null assertion needed
```

For your second example, neither is great IMO. If this field is only initialized once, the best option is using `by lazy`:

```
private val cachedVariable by lazy { SomeClass() }

fun getCachedVariable(): SomeClass {
    return cachedVariable // the first call will initialize
}
```

If for some reason you can't or won't use `by lazy`, you should read up on [Double-checked locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking), which is the safe and performant way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers explain well why Kotlin requires the `!!` null assertion in this case. But generally, when you're accessing an instance variable like this, you want to capture its value at a single moment and then do null checks on *that* capture.

```
class Example2 {
  private var cachedVariable: SomeClass? = null

  fun getCachedVariable(): SomeClass {
    val cachedVariableValue = cachedVariable
    if (cachedVariableValue == null) {
      // Do something
    } else {
      // Flow typing works here; the type of
      // cachedVariableValue is SomeClass now.
    }
  }
}
```

Other threads can modify the value of an instance variable at any time. But if your function creates a local variable with `val`, then *nobody*, not even that function itself, can modify that value again, so if you check that that `val` is non-null, that check is guaranteed to be good forever.

Now, in your case, you're also modifying `cachedVariable`, so if this is code that's going to run in a multithreaded environment, you'll need to properly lock it with a mutex or monitor. Java and Kotlin make this easy with `synchronized`, but you still have to do it.